# Restrict access to Data Studio Community Visualization

Tags: google-cloud-platform, looker-studio

I created a community chart for Google DataStudio, but I want to restrict its access to only my team members.

Is there a way to achieve this?

The community chart is in a cloud storage bucket, but if I change the public permissions to restrict (for example, just giving access to myself), I cannot use my graph with Google Data Studio.

[image]

Comment: https://developers.google.com/datastudio/solution/blocks/using-service-accounts

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not possible. Community Visualizations need to be publicly available to work.

https://developers.google.com/datastudio/visualization/upload-viz

Think in community visualizations like webpages. There is no reason to make them not publicly available and they should not hold sensitive data.

However, if you don't share the bucket name, I doubt anyone will be able to use it. If you're neurotic, use a long-random-not-easy-to-guess name and think that it is a password.